# How can we decompose $\text{Var}[\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m f(A_i,B_j)]$?

Tags: variance, random-variable, covariance, sum

Formulas for decomposing the variance of a summation of random variables can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) but what is the variance of a double summation of a function of random variables? That is, are there formulas we can use to decompose the following expression?

$$
\text{Var}[\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m f(A_i,B_j)]
$$

Image of page where I saw this expression:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that:

$$\text{Var}\Big(\sum_i X_i\Big)=\sum_i\sum_j\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)$$

We also know that:

$$\text{Cov}\Big(\sum_i^n X_i,\sum_j^nY_j\Big)=\sum_i^n\sum_j^n\text{Cov}(X_i,Y_j)$$

By extension:

\begin{align}
\text{Var}\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^m f(A_i,B_j)\bigg)\Bigg) &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\text{Cov}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^m f(A_i,B_j),\sum_{j=1}^m f(A_k,B_j) \bigg) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n \Bigg( \sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{l=1}^m\text{Cov}\big(f(A_i,B_j), f(A_k,B_l) \big)\Bigg) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^m\text{Cov}\big(f(A_i,B_j), f(A_k,B_l) \big)
\end{align}

This can be simplified further also, depending on what needs to be done finally.

Comment: Great, thanks, that explains an expression I saw in a paper earlier (apart from the fact that they just use one index $n$ instead of two indices $m$ and $n$). I have attached an image of this expression to my original post. Do you know how they managed to simplify it further to $12$ expressions?

Comment: The added pic in your question is further simplification that can be done by considering special cases when $i=k, j=l$ simultaneously and separately.